# how to set image folder path for live server in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am having following key for image path in web.config file

```
<add key="ImagePath" value="\Images\"/>
```

I want to store images in this folder on live site how the value for this will be set here
whether the domain name will come because the images are not storing in this path its working fine on local site but not on live site

Comment: You have set the path, now its time to use this path from server-side code to place images, I would suggest to elaborate your question in detail, and show what have you done so far.

Comment: On live site make sure that Images folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

If this key is in your **web.config** file

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ImagePath" value="\Images\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then in your server-side code, you can get the image path from configuration to get the Physical Path for storage like so:

```
var imagePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(imagePath);

if (File.Exists(physicalPath))
{
    //... store your images ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue.

When the IIS worker process tries to write to the /Images/ folder, it is unable as it does not have write permissions.   When you run your website locally via Visual Studio it gives the worker process full rights to any folder in your solution - this may be why you can run it locally but not on the server.

You would need to give the IIS worker process user both Read and Write access to the /Images/ folder.

However you must ensure you do not give your IIS Worker process user the Read & Execute permission.